# Application validates XML against XSD: allow XSD reference in XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd

My application validates a XML against a XSD (**which is in the jar**):

```
private Document createAndValidate(Schema schema) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
  DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  documentBuilderFactory.setValidating(false); // DTD validation
  documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);
  documentBuilderFactory.setSchema(schema);

  DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  documentBuilder.setErrorHandler(new SaxErrorHandler());

  return documentBuilder.parse(file.toFile());
}
```

That works fine so far.

But since it's easier to create the XML with the XSD (**which could be anywhere on the local computer**) referenced, the XML starts like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Definition
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="C:\definition_schema.xsd">
```

Now, when my application parses that XML file, it fails to validate because of this XSD reference:

> cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is
>   not allowed to appear in 'Definition'

I tried to add `<xs:attribute name="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" type="xs:string" />` to the `Definition` element, but that attribute name isn't valid.

I could open the XML file and remove the attribute before I (re)open and validate it. But there must be a better solution.

How do I handle this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`xmlns:xsi` is a namespace declaration, so change to `setNamespaceAware(true)`.

With it set to `false`, the two attributes are just generic attributes whose name happen to contain a `:`. With `true`, the `:` become a separator between the namespace prefix (`xmlns` and `xsi`) and the namespace'd attribute.

You will of course also need to add a `xmlns="http://example.org/MyNamespace"` attribute, matching the target namespace of the schema.

Comment: Great, thanks! My schema has no namespace: `<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`, so I don't need to add the attribute, right? Now, with `setNamespaceAware(true)`, the `xsi` is recognized as Namespace. But I don't understand why the `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation` attribute is now tolerated by the XSD. It's still not defined there.

Comment: Becuase the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance` namespace is defined but the specification: XML Schema Part 1: Structures, section 2.6 [Schema-Related Markup in Documents Being Validated](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Instance_Document_Constructions).